# Macruby prefPane - Nothing works

Tags: ruby, macruby

I've created a super simple example application using Macruby.
The problem is that the prefpane won't work, nothing happens.

I've created a button, that has a callback in the [Main.rb](https://github.com/oleander/MacRubyTesting/blob/master/Main.rb) file.
When someone clicks on the button the label should change value to "Some data".

The link to the Main.rb file also contains the non working example project.

There is only 3 lines of code added.

Comment: have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581667/interface-builder-not-seeing-outlets-with-macruby I had similar problems until I reinstalled Xcode and then MacRuby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems were being shown in your console messages (Console.app). Or if you would start System Preferences.app from the command-line you could have seen the messages there. Anyways, copy-pasting from [the commit message](https://github.com/alloy/MacRubyTesting/commit/c338e716160f4ae82cd64fcadc2c2ab5b9f2fedb):

- The Main.rb file was never being loaded in the runtime with a call like: require 'Main'.
- The resources path of the bundle isn't added to the load path by default, so I did this in PrefPane.rb.
- Why do you really need the Main class instead of using the PrefPane class?
- You had the `text' outlet of Main hooked up to the content view in the nib, not to the actual text label.

Last but not least, since MacRuby is still a ‘young’ project, I urge people to ask their questions there, so the actual community can help out.

Comment: The reason I dont use the PrefPane class to place my code is because the accessors and methods won't show up in interface builder. I added an example to the project on Github. Here is the code: https://github.com/oleander/MacRubyTesting/blob/37e6801032c6160e95e55e3138a83c452815bbfb/build/Debug/Testing.prefPane/Contents/Resources/PrefPane.rb

Comment: Hmm, I guess that might be because IB prefers the objective-c definition over the Ruby one. Can you check if you remove the PrefPane.m/h references from the project IB does pick the Ruby file up?

Comment: Regardless of that bit about the PrefPane/Main classes, does it now work for you? If so, mind flagging the answer as ‘answered’? :)