# MacRuby Can't access Received Action with Xcode Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, macruby

I move slowly forward checking every bug report I can find to get MacRuby on my Macbook Air (OSX 10.9) with Xcode (Version 5.0.1) running. After fixing some issues I'm still stuck in the [Tutorial](https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/wiki/Creating-a-simple-application).

My problem, I can't connect the actions by dragging them onto the App Delegate object. I know there were some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581667/interface-builder-not-seeing-outlets-with-macruby) but even after [following the instructions](http://lldong.github.com/blog/2012/03/05/xcode-4-dot-3-macruby-compatible-problem-workaround/) there it doesn't work.

Is there anything else to consider that I maybe missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in an issue (https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/issues/228) writing a header file with all the actions and buttons worked for me.